# JavaScript write rowCount to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following JavaScript function to add a row to my table. I want to write to the table the value of the current rowCount.

My function is:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;



    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {


        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

        newcell.childNodes[0].value = rowCount;
    }
}
```

My HTML table:

```
<TABLE id="dataTable" border="0">

    <TR style="display:none;">
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk2"/></TD>
        <TD><script>document.write(rowCount);</script><select name="room[][]" multiple="MULTIPLE" >
            <option value="" selected ></option>
        </select></TD>

    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I have tried `<script>document.write(rowCount);</script>` and `<script>document.write(this.rowCount);</script>`. The first returning the error: Can't find variable rowCount and the second: undefined is not an object.

It sounds a bit messy but the idea is that I want to pass the rowCount value into the name of `<select name="room[][]>` giving me:

```
<select name="room[0][]>
<select name="room[1][]>
<select name="room[2][]>
```

Comment: `rowCount` is a _local_ variable, outside of that context it's

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the *same exact functionality* you're already using to write values to the page?  Identify the target element that needs to display the value and set its contents to that value.

Comment: Just let you know that jsfiddle is always helpful

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tn88wL5e/).

Comment: Fiddle is great @Regent thank you. How would I append the name of the select? I'm presuming somehow appending .length?

Comment: Yes, it's all about `<tr>`s `.length`. Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tn88wL5e/1/).